# Self type annotation not recognized by compiler

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, self-type

I want a class to force it's subclasses to implement a sub-trait to a trait and tried this:

```
sealed trait TA
sealed trait TB extends TA
sealed trait TC extends TA

sealed trait CA {
  this: TA =>
}
final class CB extends CA with TB
final class CC extends CA with TC

def ca: CA = if (scala.util.Random.nextBoolean) new CB()
             else new CC()
def ta: TA = ca
```

With the code below I get the following compiler error:

```
Error:(16, 16) type mismatch;
 found   : CA
 required: TA
  def ta: TA = ca
```

1. Could a CA not be a TA when I have the self type annotation: "this: TA =>" or is this a glitch in the compiler?
2. Are there better ways to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self type is a kind of "private inheritance" (well, it's not really inheritance, but similar), you can't use it outside of the class.

You could have your `CA` implement the conversion if you have to:

```
trait CA { this: TA => 
  def ta: TA = this
}
```

As to your question about a "better way to implement this", it's hard to tell, because it's not clear at all what it is you are trying to do here.

Why not have `CA` extend `TA` for example? Like I said, self-type is very similar to a "private inheritance", and you sound like you want inheritance, but don't want it to be private. So ... why not just use inheritance?

Comment: I want a class (CA) to force it’s subclasses (CB and CC) to implement a subtype (TB or TC) of a trait TA. I have a method that returns a CA that I want to reuse in situations where the TA-aspect of the class is needed.

If I have CA extend TA it wouldn’t be a compiler error if the subclasses didn’t extend TA or TB.

Interestingly the compiler accepts: def ca: TA = if (scala.util.Random.nextBoolean) new CB() else new CC()

Comment: Yes, of course, it accepts it, because both CB and CC are subclasses of TA. CA isn't. You are not forcing your subclasses implement a subclass of TA with your approach either. They could still just extend TA itself.

Answer (score 0):

`CA` by itself doesn't extend `TA`, self annotation means that you can only use `CA` in combination with `TA` when extending. It's a hint for the compiler. In fact if you look at bytecode `CA` doesn't extend anything.

Both `CB` and `CC` do extend `TA` through `TB` and `TC`, that's why

```
def ca: TA = if (scala.util.Random.nextBoolean) new CB() else new CC()
```

works.